# Verse about becoming grateful

Tags: tanach, hakaras-hatov

Is there any verse in the Tanach which tells/hints on how to become grateful to God for his gifts?

In what sense should one be grateful to God? What I mean is how a person can develop the feeling of being grateful toward God?

Added note : I guess I should clear this with an example, God gave us everything that we need. Let's talk about one blessing for example. The sun. How does one develops a feeling of gratefulness toward God,  specifically for creating the Sun.

Saying thanks to God is a form of an expression of gratitude towards God. Meaning the feeling it self must already be there in order to be able to truly express it. If you're thanking God for something without having the feeling of actually being grateful about it, you're not actually thanking God. Your mouth is just uttering something your heart does not.

My question is not about the way one should say thanks to God. Rather how does one can develop the feeling of being grateful in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

[*Tehillim 118:1*](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.118.1?lang=he)

> הוֹד֣וּ לַיהוָ֣ה כִּי־ט֑וֹב כִּ֖י לְעוֹלָ֣ם חַסְדּֽוֹ׃
>
> Praise the
> LORD, for He is good,  His steadfast love is eternal.

This is a standard verse used to convey thanks and praise to God. Used specifically during the [special] Hallel service (also, see [Sukah 3:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sukkah.3.9)) and each verse in the rest of this Psalm 118 mimics the first half of this verse. (כי לעולם חסדו)

As well, on the Shabbath, during the *verses of praise* portion of davening, this entire psalm is added in an extra praising and thanking for the Shabbath.

The way you phrased your question *’to God for **his gifts**’,* seems to offer a reading of either one’s gifts from God specifically, or that God bestows gifts in general, either way I can say I often hear personally in the Jewish community and orthodox culture surrounding me, when someone feels in an instance the need to quickly show gratitude towards God, you might hear ‘*Hodu Lashem!’*, or in other cases a full recitation of the verse with Gods name being probably uttered.

Comment: Can you edit to explain how this verse describes a means of becoming grateful?

Answer (score 0):

[***Tehillim 23:1***](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16244#v=1)

> :מִזְמ֥וֹר לְדָוִ֑ד יְהֹוָ֥ה רֹ֜עִ֗י לֹ֣א אֶחְסָֽר
>
> A song of David. The Lord is my shepherd; I shall not want.

[***Tehillim 100:4-5***](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16321#v=4)

> :בֹּ֚אוּ שְׁעָרָ֨יו | בְּתוֹדָ֗ה חֲצֵֽרֹתָ֥יו בִּתְהִלָּ֑ה ה֥וֹדוּ ל֜֗וֹ בָּֽרְכ֥וּ שְׁמֽוֹ: כִּי־ט֣וֹב יְ֖הֹוָה לְעוֹלָ֣ם חַסְדּ֑וֹ וְעַד־דֹּ֥ר וָ֜דֹ֗ר אֱמֽוּנָתֽוֹ
>
> Come into His gates with thanksgiving, [into] His courtyards with praise; give thanks to Him, bless His name. For the Lord is good; His kindness is forever, and until generation after generation is His faith.

[***Tehillim 145:16***](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16366/jewish/Chapter-145.htm#v=16)

> :פּוֹתֵ֥חַ אֶת־יָדֶ֑ךָ וּמַשְׂבִּ֖יעַ לְכָל־חַ֣י רָצֽוֹן
>
> You open Your hand and satisfy every living thing [with] its desire.

Comment: The second quote is the only one that has anything to do with gratitude. The others are verses that one may recite in gratitude, perhaps, but they don’t discuss it directly.

Comment: This is a verse of how one should thanks G-d. But how is one able to develop the feeling of being grateful toward G-d?

Comment: @Tomsofty33 Because he opens his hand to satisfy every living thing. He provides us with everything we need.

Comment: I clarify my question please let me know what are your comments about it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the beginning of Pesukei D'Zimrah work for you?
Divrei HaYamim 1 16:8-12

> הוֹד֚וּ לַֽיהֹוָה֙ קִרְא֣וּ בִשְׁמ֔וֹ הוֹדִ֥יעוּ בָֽעַמִּ֖ים עֲלִילֹתָֽיו: שִׁ֚ירוּ לוֹ֙ זַמְּרוּ־ל֔וֹ שִׂ֖יחוּ בְּכָל־נִפְלְאֹתָֽיו: הִתְהַֽלְלוּ֙ בְּשֵׁ֣ם קָדְשׁ֔וֹ יִשְׂמַ֕ח לֵ֖ב מְבַקְשֵׁ֥י יְהֹוָֽה: דִּרְשׁ֚וּ יְהֹוָה֙ וְעֻזּ֔וֹ בַּקְּשׁ֥וּ פָנָ֖יו תָּמִֽיד: זִכְר֗וּ נִפְלְאֹתָיו֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר עָשָׂ֔ה מֹֽפְתָ֖יו וּמִשְׁפְּטֵי־פִֽיהוּ:

Edit for clarification:

> Give thanks to the Lord, call out in His Name; make His exploits known among the peoples. Sing to Him, play music to Him, speak of all His wonders. Glory in His holy Name; may the heart of those who seek the Lord rejoice. Search for the Lord and His might; seek His presence constantly. Remember His wonders, which He performed, His miracles and the judgments of His mouth.

This seems like a pretty specific directive to give thanks, how to give thanks. And perhaps, at the end there, "Remember His wonders", why. Jews say this at the beginning of every morning prayer service.

Comment: This is a command. Not how do you actually incite / create the feeling of gratitude in you.